# Make it hard to tamper with game data on non-jailbroken devices

Tags: ios, security, jailbreak

We are developing a game where all the game logic is executed locally (no server back-end) and would like to make it difficult to tamper with game data (such as user credits, game settings and so on).

Now, it's even possible on non-jailbroken devices to access the filesystem and change game data - so, for example if user inventory stats are stored in a plist file, it's very easy to edit them.

If we move game settings from plist files to source-code files, such that they get compiled into the binary, it will require at least a modification of the binary to change settings. On non-jailbroken phones - will modified binaries still run, or does the apple codesigning prevent from modifying the binaries in any way?

What are some quick and easy to implement measures to make it a bit harder to tamper with game-data (especially on non-jailbroken phones. Optimally we'd like to provide some kind of security that will at least require a jailbreak to make modifications to the game)?

so - to summarize the questions:

1. can the binary part of an iOS app be modified and still run on non-jailbroken devices?
2. what are some quick and easy to implement measures to make it harder to tamper with gamedata on non-jailbroken devices?

Comment: On a non-jailbroken device, application data and binary resides in a sandbox - so it's (basically) impossible to access data from another application. Why do you think it's easy? Why do you think data in binaries will be more difficult to access than data on dedicated files?

Comment: it is easy - i followed some simple steps on my non-jailbroken ipad to change gamedata of the game 'apoc wars'. it seems it's possible to access all files on the filesystem without having to jailbreak: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BYrUyAQ7Po

Comment: So, it seems the developers of that game have made the game data _shareable_ (through iTunes). This has to be done _explicitly_ by the developers. The default is that any document in folder `/Documents` is not visible (since encrypted). Making the documents folder shareable is an application feature which can be enabled via key `UIFileSharingEnabled ` in the `Info.plist` file.  The other quite bizarre thing in that game is, that user's data "sync" to the "server" data (server takes over user data). That's fatal wrong game design.  ;)

Comment: Uhps, noticed that the guy is using iExplorer - where it is possible to browse the contents of the device's disk. There are other tools that can do that, too. So, in order to avoid that user read the data, you'll need to encrypt them. The sandbox will just prevent other apps on the device to access other app's data. The data is not (necessarily) encrypted on disk (but it can, when set by the user).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. No. The application will be required to be signed again.
2. A simple but not unbreakable measurement is to safe the data in a secure container (key chain for example) or encrypt it yourself before you safe it to disk. An attacker now have to monitor a running app to get to the decrypted data in memory - or need to crack the secure store.

There are a few ways on iOS (and Mac OS X) where you can accomplish to encrypt and decrypt data. One way is pretty nicely described here in the official docs:
[Encrypting and Decrypting Data](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW9).

Comment: thank you for your answer. regarding 1. does this even apply if the filesize remains unchanged? does ios calculate a checksum of the whole binary each time it's executed?

regarding 2: do you know if iOS offers something like that out of the box?

Comment: Yes, if the content changes, the sign will break. Regarding your second, see my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the binary as it would invalidate the signature.  I would just use some sort of encryption on the data you don't want users to modify.  You can make this as simple or as complex as you want.  I don't think iOS provides any kind of encryption services out of the box, but you don't need to go hog wild with it - a simple [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) algorithm would do, since we're not talking about password-level security here.  If you want, you can even add a checksum on the encrypted data, then invalidate it if the checksums don't match.

Comment: I still wonder how it can invalidate the signature if the binary is modified but stays the same size? A mechanism that could check if the binary was unchanged would require to calculate a new checksum out of the full binary each time it's run, which depending on binary size would take quite some time, no?